# Why must I use \x1b not \ to represent an escape character

Tags: c, escaping, control-characters, low-level-io

I've read that `\x1b` represents the escape character, but isn't `'\'` by itself the escape character? A tutorial wants me to write

```
write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\x1b[2J", 4);
```

to clear the screen. Why won't `'\[2J'` do the job?

Comment: Two different escape characters for two completely different things.

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: `\x1b` represents an ESC character - look at an ASCII chart. \ is a backslash, which the C compiler uses to escape characters. `ESC` is not the same as `escape character`. The line of code outputs the `ESC` character, followed by a sequence of three other characters (`[23`) for a total of 4 characters.

Comment: what is the difference between an escape character an an ESC character?

Comment: " escape character"  is a generic concept.  `ESC` is a specifier ASCII value: 27.

Comment: You could use `\033` to make it an octal representation of the ESC character.  It is confusing, but there are two different meanings for escape here — and the difference has been outlined by Ken White.

Answer (score 5):

Although this question is a bit old, I'll give my two cents using the `\n` as an example.

Although the [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) `escape character` is `\x1B`, and `n` is `\x6E`, it's not possible to insert a `\n` character into a string using `\x1B\x6E`, for two reasons:

1. The `ESC` character in ASCII table, and the escape character `\` in programming languages are two different things.
2. Programming languages search for `\n` (as a single entity), **in the source code** (before we're in bytes level) to convert it into line-feed bytes, so `\x1B\x6E` **will not get converted** to anything. Thus, even if you use `\x5C\x6E` in the source code(an ASCII `\` and an ASCII `n`), it won't get converted to a line-feed.

Example in Python:

```
>>> print("Hello\x5C\x6EWorld")
Hello\nWorld
# if one still insists on inserting a new line using an ascii line-feed (\x0A), they can do:
>>> print("Hello\x0AWorld")
Hello
World
```

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate the comments of Ken and Jonathan a bit: Escaping here is a general concept. It basically implies the change of something's interpretation.
The escape character in ASCII originates from teletype machines, where the appearance of ESC has changed the interpretation of the following character. It is used in the same way by many terminals. E.g., the appearance of ESC before the string `[2J` cause the the string (i.e. the characters `[`,`2`, and `J`) aren't **displayed** at the terminal, but interpreted as the **command** "*clear entire screen*". Thus, the escape character has changed the interpretation **mode**.

However, there is no straightforward way to enter the ASCII escape character (because pressing there ESC key at your keyboard usually changes a mode in your editor, terminal or whatever), and even if you could, the allowed character set of the language C doesn't include it. Now, you need a second level of escaping: C has its own character for escaping: `\`. It changes the meaning of the next character(s). E.g., a precedent backslash changes the meaning (interpretation) of the following character `n` into newline. In addition, the `\x` (or `\0`, respectively) let the C parser interpret the following two (three) characters as hexadecimal (octal) number - instead as the characters themselves - and insert the character that corresponds to that very code number. Since the ASCII code for escape has the number 27 (decimal), or 1b (hexadecimal), or 33 (octal), respectively, you generate the ASCII escape character in C by `\x1b` or `\033`.

With other words, you escape in C with `\` to generate the ASCII escape character, that in turn forces an escaping at your terminal.